# Error: Could not extract Info.plist from application: Could not parse plist file '/Pathof.appfile/Info.plist' as XML

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, visual-studio-2017, appium-ios

I am currently trying to run a C# NUnit test script from Visual Studio Community 2017 for MAC in integration with Appium. Software configurations are MAC OS- 10.12.6, Appium Desktop client 1.4.0,iOS Simulator iPhone 7 (OS version 10.3.1), xCode -8.3.3. Our development team has provided with an iOS app built in debug mode by selecting target device as a simulator(for x86 architecture). When I run the C# Script following appium log is generated:

```
[info] [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.7.2
[info] [Appium] Non-default server args:
[info] [Appium]   address: 127.0.0.1
[info] [Appium]   sessionOverride: true
[info] [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723[info] [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"PlatformName":"iOS","PlatformVersion":"10.3","deviceName":"iPhone 7","udid":"043A59DD-D537-4E9E-B9FD-FAC5B1CA2FBF","app":"Users//apple//Desktop//IPA//LighthouseApp.iOS//bin//iPhoneSimulator//Debug//LighthouseApp.iOS.app","automationName":"XCUITest","shouldWaitForQuiescence":"true","platformName":"iOS"}}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"PlatformName":"iOS","PlatformVersion":"10.3","deviceName":"iPhone 7","udid":"043A59DD-D537-4E9E-B9FD-FAC5B1CA2FBF","app":"Users//apple//Desktop//IPA//LighthouseApp.iOS//bin//iPhoneSimulator//Debug//LighthouseApp.iOS.app","automationName":"XCUITest","shouldWaitForQuiescence":"true","platformName":"iOS"},null,null]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1520660747951 (11:15:47 GMT+0530 (IST))
[info] [Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.70.0) session
[info] [Appium] Capabilities:
[info] [Appium]   PlatformName: iOS
[info] [Appium]   PlatformVersion: 10.3
[info] [Appium]   deviceName: iPhone 7
[info] [Appium]   udid: 043A59DD-D537-4E9E-B9FD-FAC5B1CA2FBF
[info] [Appium]   app: Users//apple//Desktop//IPA//LighthouseApp.iOS//bin//iPhoneSimulator//Debug//LighthouseApp.iOS.app
[info] [Appium]   automationName: XCUITest
[info] [Appium]   shouldWaitForQuiescence: true
[info] [Appium]   platformName: iOS
[debug] [BaseDriver] 
[debug] [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities [] and MJSONWP desired capabilities  were provided
[warn] [BaseDriver] Expected W3C "capabilities" to be a JSON Object but was provided with: []
[warn] [BaseDriver] Falling back to MJSONWP desired capabilities
[warn] [BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: PlatformName, PlatformVersion, shouldWaitForQuiescence.
[info] [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: dfc78eed-1152-4c50-95b8-945827c7eaa0[info] [iOSSim] Constructing iOS simulator for Xcode version 8.3.3 with udid '043A59DD-D537-4E9E-B9FD-FAC5B1CA2FBF'
[info] [XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: '043A59DD-D537-4E9E-B9FD-FAC5B1CA2FBF', real device: false[debug] [XCUITest] Xcode version set to '8.3.3' (tools v9.2.0.0.1.1510905681)[debug] [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to '10.3'
[info] [XCUITest] No platformVersion specified. Using device version: '10.3'
[info] [BaseDriver] Using local app 'Users//apple//Desktop//IPA//LighthouseApp.iOS//bin//iPhoneSimulator//Debug//LighthouseApp.iOS.app'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'appConfigured' logged at 1520660767421 (11:16:07 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Checking whether app 'Users//apple//Desktop//IPA//LighthouseApp.iOS//bin//iPhoneSimulator//Debug//LighthouseApp.iOS.app' is actually present on file system
[debug] [XCUITest] App is present[debug] [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to '10.3'
[info] [XCUITest] No platformVersion specified. Using device version: '10.3'
[info] [BaseDriver] Using local app 'Users//apple//Desktop//IPA//LighthouseApp.iOS//bin//iPhoneSimulator//Debug//LighthouseApp.iOS.app'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'appConfigured' logged at 1520660767421 (11:16:07 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Checking whether app 'Users//apple//Desktop//IPA//LighthouseApp.iOS//bin//iPhoneSimulator//Debug//LighthouseApp.iOS.app' is actually present on file system
[debug] [XCUITest] App is present
[error] [Support] Error: Could not parse plist file '/Users/apple/Desktop/IPA/LighthouseApp.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/LighthouseApp.iOS.app/Info.plist' as XML: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:69:13)
    at Object.parsePlistFile$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-support/lib/plist.js:43:11)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at <anonymous>
 **Error: Could not parse plist file '/Users/apple/Desktop/IPA/LighthouseApp.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/LighthouseApp.iOS.app/Info.plist' as XML: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined**
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:69:13)
    at Object.parsePlistFile$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-support/lib/plist.js:43:11)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at <anonymous>
[error] [iOS] Error: Could not extract Info.plist from application: Could not parse plist file '/Users/apple/Desktop/IPA/LighthouseApp.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/LighthouseApp.iOS.app/Info.plist' as XML: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:69:13)
    at extractPlist$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/lib/app-utils.js:14:9)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at <anonymous>
 Error: Could not extract Info.plist from application: Could not parse plist file '/Users/apple/Desktop/IPA/LighthouseApp.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/LighthouseApp.iOS.app/Info.plist' as XML: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:69:13)
    at extractPlist$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/lib/app-utils.js:14:9)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at <anonymous>
[error] [XCUITest] Error: Could not extract Info.plist from application: Could not parse plist file '/Users/apple/Desktop/IPA/LighthouseApp.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/LighthouseApp.iOS.app/Info.plist' as XML: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:69:13)
    at extractPlist$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/lib/app-utils.js:14:9)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at <anonymous>
 Error: Could not extract Info.plist from application: Could not parse plist file '/Users/apple/Desktop/IPA/LighthouseApp.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/LighthouseApp.iOS.app/Info.plist' as XML: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:69:13)
    at extractPlist$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/lib/app-utils.js:14:9)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at <anonymous>
[debug] [XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
[error] [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not extract Info.plist from application: Could not parse plist file '/Users/apple/Desktop/IPA/LighthouseApp.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/LighthouseApp.iOS.app/Info.plist' as XML: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:69:13)
    at extractPlist$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/lib/app-utils.js:14:9)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at <anonymous>
[info] [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 19920 ms - 374
```

Note- I have given .app path of app in debug folder. If I use the .ipa file the app installs on the simulator, launches and crashes immediately. **I am stuck at the info.plist file that is not parsing. Please guide me through , all suggestions are appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

the app build was not for simulator ,it was compiled in release mode to deploy on real devices. Hence there was a problem of launching the app on simulator. Make sure carthage is installed, include udid in capabilites and device name must be kept as only "iPhone" and also use the capability AutomationName as XCUITest.
Your Appium desktop app must be installed into the application folder.